# Как правильно объявлять функции для работы с закрытой структурой в классе

Tags: c++

```
template <class SetType> class set{
public:
    ...
private:
    ...

    struct list{//структура, в которой хранятся элементы множеств
        SetType key;
        list *next;
    };
    list *root;
    list *head;

    //функции для работы со списком
    list *search(SetType key);//поиск элемента в списке
    list *search(set<SetType> &ob, SetType key);//поиск элемента в списке
    list *search_el(SetType id);//проверка множества на уникальность элементов
    ...
};
```

при компиляции вылетает 3 ошибки

"expected constructor destructor or type conversion before '*' token"

и относятся к такой записи

```
template <class SetType> set<SetType>::list *set<SetType>::search(SetType key){
    ...
}
```

http://pastebin.com/bBZSrCE4 вся программка

Comment: Весь код можете привести? Такое ощущение, что ошибка где-то раньше - например незакрытая скобка.

Comment: Да, а в template <class SetType> class set. после > можно сделать перевод строки, читабельнее будет.

Comment: На каком этапе перестало компилироваться? После добавления какого функционала? Или вы все это на одном дыхании написали, а потом решили собрать?..

Comment: Под g++ не собирается. Надо разбираться.
http://pastebin.com/mCeYNamK

Comment: Под g++ и не должно, судя по #include <conio.h> =)

Answer (score 2):

Нашел причину. Нужно написать:

```
template <class SetType>
typename set<SetType>::list *set<SetType>::search(SetType key){
...
}
```

Это нужно для того, чтобы компилятор знал, что set<settype>::list это имя типа.